# Set theme in Collapsing Toolbar when collapsed and not

Tags: android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How could I change the arrow's colors and toolbar icon when not collapsed.
When collapsed I would like to leave it like this, white and black. The problem is when it's not collapsed I'd like to leave the icons and arrow white.

Imagens below:

Image1: (Where do I want to change the color)

### [image]

Image2: (That's right...)

### [image]

Code XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="180dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/hair"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
           
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNomeCidade"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="155dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="São Paulo - SP"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="155dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp">


                    <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_info24"
                            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                            android:cropToPadding="false"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:clickable="true"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Sobre"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />-->
            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
                android:background="@color/cinzaMEdio"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarPerfilEmpresa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_favorite_border"
                        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:clickable="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="2.650"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_date_range24"
                        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:clickable="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Agenda"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_collections24"
                        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:clickable="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Fotos"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_chat_bubble_outline24"
                        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:clickable="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Mensagem"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:background="#FAFAFA"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

How could you do to have that custom style?
Sorry the English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this theme in your activity

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @TiagoIB no its just change your theme apply this theme in to your activity and let me know if any query